# Javascript - filtering elements by an array not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function where I am making an array of tags on click of the filter buttons. What I would also like to do is to after that go through that array, and filter elements that don't have that class and hide them. But it is not working.

This is the code:

```
$('.filter-button').click(function() {


$(this).toggleClass('active');

  var activeTags = $('.filter-button.active');
  var tags = [];
  var articles = $('.article-list');

  $(activeTags).each(function() {
    tags.push('.' + $(this).text());
  });

  $(articles).not(tags.join(",")).hide();

});
```

And this is the html:

```
    <div class="small-6 medium-4 large-3 column article-list {% for tag in entry.tags %} {{ tag }} {% endfor %}">
      <img src="{{ entry.topImage.first().getUrl('square') }}" alt="">
      <div class="image-text">
         <h5>{{ entry.title }}</h5>
         <a href="{{ entry.url }}">Les mer</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Update**

Gulp wasn't updating so I didn't see that it is actually working, but it is still not working as it should be. The elements are not toggled properly, once hidden they are not shown again. Not sure why, what am I doing wrong?

This is the updated code:

```
$('.filter-button').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');

  var activeTags = $('.filter-button.active');
  var tags = [];
  var articles = $('.article-list');

  $(activeTags).each(function() {
    tags.push('.' + $(this).text());
  });

  $(articles).not(tags.join(",")).toggle();

});
```

Comment: articles.not(".foo").hide()

Comment: But, how can I pass an array as a selector?

Comment: show your html code also

Comment: .not(yourArray.join(",")) ??

Comment: I have tried that, but it is not working, the elements are not hidden

Comment: Why are you using an array at all, why not use `filter` or `map` and create a new collection without the elements ?

Comment: Try `articles.not(tags.join(",")).hide();` instead of `$(articles).not(tags.join(",")).hide();`. `articles` is already a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you just need to hide the articles before you call `.toggle()`.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxz1dx2p/)**

```
$(articles).hide().not(tags.join(",")).toggle();
//          ^^^^^^
```

---

Side notes:

- Building an array from the text value is not very robust. Whitespace on the button could break your selector.
- `articles` is already a jQuery object so there's no need to wrap it again, although jQuery will handle this and it won't cause an issue.

Comment: It worked with show, not hide, just like in your fiddle, thanks for your help and notes!